# Dumping a huge array in Intellij-Idea debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a way in Idea to dump the content of a large - very - array of ints into the clipboard ?

'copy value' on an array return nothing.

Comment: Workaround: open evalute expression window, type `Arrays.toString(yourArr)` and copy the result of that ...

Comment: When the array is not very big, I just expand the objects in the array manually. Then I CTRL+A select everything and paste it somewhere.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To get the value in the clipboard using copy value, you need to define a "Java Data Type Renderer" to interpret the content of your array.

- Right click on your array variable
- Select "View as->Create..."
- In the "Java Data Type Renderers" window, create a new entry, set "When rendering a node, use following expression" with `Arrays.toString(this)`.
- Apply, select your array variable and do `Ctrl-C` to get the content.

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click variable
2. Evaluate expression
3. Type `*nameOfYourArray*.toString()`
4. Click evaluate
5. `Ctrl-C` to get content