# Is there any way to save variable and its values during debugging in intellij?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am struggling with an error. I cannot find it. Is there a way to compare the debugging results before and after a change in intellij. Other solutions will be also welcomed.

I am explaining my scenario here.

I am debugging a class and at a break point, there are three variables. I named it `variableA`, `variableB` and `variableC`. For example, the debugger stops when the variableA gets its values. At that time, I would like to save the content of `variableA`. In this way, I can compare the content of `variableA` before and after the change.

Comment: Are you looking for some integrated workflow?  Because you can always copy the value to the clipboard and paste it into a text editor.  You can also compare a value to the clipboard.

Comment: Yes, but this object has more than 200 values and there is no way to copy all of them once.

Comment: Look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549721/dumping-a-huge-array-in-intellij-idea-debugger

Comment: would be nice if someone adds this as a feature request for intellij

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing, you can do in your case, open all the values of a variable and select all and copy-paste like the Mark pointed out in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. On any user-defined types, never use `toString()` for any production purposes; `toString()` should be reserved for debugging purposes only.
2. Every object should have a `toString()` method which generates a string containing key-value pairs for all members of the object.  You can write a helper that uses reflection to automate this. It is for debugging purposes, so performance does not matter much.
3. The value of each member is obtained by invoking its `toString()` method, so your helper needs to keep track of objects that it has already visited, and refrain from recursing into them, to avoid the stack overflow that would otherwise be caused each time you have a circular reference somewhere.
4. Once you have all this in place, you can always ask the debugger to copy the "value" of an object to the clipboard, and then later compare the value of another object against the value in the clipboard.

This works because copying the "value" of an object to the clipboard does not actually copy the value of that object to the clipboard; what it does is that it invokes `toString()` on that object, and it copies the result to the clipboard.

Answer (score -2):

Would a print statement work? you could use a global counter to keep track of which pass you are at and then compare the values in the consoles.

Comment: It is much more complicated than a situation, which can be handled with console.